# Error - Can not see text in visual code when doing a request

Tags: node.js

I have a simple basic node.js entry file by the name of index.js and the below code for this file is as following:

```
const express = require("express");
const expressApp = require("./express-app/test.js");
const { PORT } = require("./config");
const { databaseConnection } = require("./database");

const StartServer = async () => {
  const app = express();

  //database connection
  await databaseConnection();

  expressApp(app);

  app
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Customer is listening on port ${PORT}`))
    .on("error", (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      process.exit();
    });
};

StartServer();
```

and also have a file by the name of test.js with the following code as below:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb" }));
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "1mb" }));
  app.use(cors);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

  //   Listen to Events //
  app.use("/app-events", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Had reached");
  });
};
```

When I do a request with url http://localhost:*portnumber*/app-events, I can not see "Had reached" in the console.

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `app.get(...)` instead of `app.use(..)`

Comment: thank you, I have used app.get(...) but still not working!